# Get all value of specific data attribute

Tags: jquery

I have `data-tablet-src` more than one as you see and I want to list them with key and value for example like this:

```
data-tablet-src => https://unsplash.it/1000/300?image=21
data-tablet-src => https://unsplash.it/1000/300?image=1001
bla...bla..bla...
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mycarousel .item img[data-tablet-src]').each(function (index, value) { 
 alert("index:" + index+"value: "+value);
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1000/300?image=68" data-tablet-src="https://unsplash.it/1000/300?image=21">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1000/300?image=43" data-tablet-src="https://unsplash.it/1000/300?image=1001">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1000/300?image=67" data-tablet-src="https://unsplash.it/1000/300?image=1002">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1000/300?image=47" data-tablet-src="https://unsplash.it/1000/300?image=1005">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1000/300?image=72" data-tablet-src="https://unsplash.it/1000/300?image=63">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the data values back to an array based on elements index like this

```
var sources = $('.carousel-inner .item img').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('tablet-src');
}).get();
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/a1qrubmw/)

Comment: adeneo thanks I'm new on jquery so I have a question how can I split with index and value ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? This just creates an array with the values, the data value from the first element would be just `sources[0]` etc

Comment: I mean I want to list them in ordered list with li element